# HttpClient, multiple async results from single call

Tags: c#, httpclient, async-await

I am stuck and have been banging my head against this problem for a couple of days now and am hoping may be able to help.

I am making a call to a http service, which when executed, will kick off a process that will send back multiple status messages.  The data comes back as a Json string which is then deserialized into an object.

The code I am trying to create already exists as a COM object in a NPAPI browser plugin, however with Google's recent decision to kill such plugins I am forced into looking into a new way to get my data.

So far I have made spectacular Swiss cheese of my working code and am able to get the first result back, and that's about it.  Here is a snippet of what I have working, the basic premise is that the service is called async and then the results are looped until I get the final status result.  Unfortunately, I know this isn't right because I get a connection terminated error when I hit the second iteration.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ContinueWith(
  (task) =>
    {
      do
      {
        var response = task.Result;

        var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(
          (readTask) =>
            {
              var data2 = readTask.Result;

              foo++;
            });
      }while (foo < 5);
    });
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks for the help!

**Edit**

Per svick's request here's some more info.  As I said the code being executed returns multiple status messages.  So I might get a message for 0% done, 5%, 20%, 25%, etc all the way up to 100%.  What I am trying to do is trap all of the messages coming back until I get the message saying the status is 100% done.

I've also tried using the ReadAsStringAsync method and it only returns the first status message and then closes the connection.

Thanks again!

**Update**
Well, it turns out I have been going about this all wrong.  Apparently there was a results call built into the service that I could query to get the data I wanted.  I guess I missed that part of the architecture meeting.

Thanks for everyone that either commented or looked at this!

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you make a request and then try to read the response 5 times. That doesn't make any sense, could you explain what exactly is your code supposed to do?

Comment: Examine the original code using Fiddler or Message Analyzer to see exactly what it's doing. From your description, it sounds like `ReadAsStringAsync` would wait until it gets *all* the responses.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use a results call to the service I wasn't aware existed.  I didn't need to figure out how to do what I had described above.